# Reading key value from consul in springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, consul

I want to read my external configs like database host and port from consul.
I want to access it in my Springboot application.
So I have created a springboot application and have added cloud config for consul configuration.
I have created an bootstrap.yml where I give my consul host and port and I am able to connect.
But I am not able to fetch any key-value pair from consul.
I have posted my bootstrap.yml below asd well.
Can somebody guide me how to do that

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      config:
              enabled: true
              data-key: config/application/datakey
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ConsulClient` and then use `getKVValue` method to read the kv configs you have set in consul.